# Sample firefox add-on "cfx test" fail, why?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I used the instructions from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation

Initiated addition and run the test. Why, even in this example I have got an error as I can continue to develop?

```
    C:\addon-sdk-1.17\bin>activate 
    Welcome to the Add-on SDK. For the docs, visit https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/ developers/docs/sdk/latest/

    (C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\bin>cd ../examples

    (C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\examples>mkdir fe

    (C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\examples>cd fe

    (C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\examples\fe>cfx init
    * lib directory created
    * data directory created
    * test directory created
    * generated jID automatically: jid1-pNW6cN0dpaDyiQ
    * package.json written
    * test/test-main.js written
    * lib/main.js written

    Your sample add-on is now ready. Do "cfx test" to test it and "cfx run" to try it.  Have fun!

    (C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\examples\fe>cfx test 
    Using binary at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'. 
    Using profile at 'c:\users\artur\appdata\local\temp\tmpxescsx.mozrunner'. 
    Running tests on Firefox 34.0.5/Gecko 34.0.5 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97 384}) under winnt/x86. .console.error: fe:   fail:   There was an uncaught Promise rejection: JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Pr omise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: PendingErrors.register  :: line 159 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise
    -backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.completePromise :: line 672 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise
    -backend.js :: Handler.prototype.process :: line 868 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise
    -backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop :: line 744 native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0 console.trace: fe:
    _ecated/unit-test.js 96 fail
    _ecated/unit-test.js 61 TestRunner.prototype._uncaughtErrorObserver
    _/Promise-backend.js 197 PendingErrors.report
    _/Promise-backend.js 209 PendingErrors.flush
    _/Promise-backend.js 611 Promise.Debugging.flushUncaughtErrors
    _ecated/unit-test.js 306 done
    _ecated/unit-test.js 529 start
    _ecated/unit-test.js 491 runNextTest
    _ecated/unit-test.js 496 startMany
    _ecated/unit-test.js 26 findAndRunTests/<
    _/Promise-backend.js 865 Handler.prototype.process
    _/Promise-backend.js 744 this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop
                         0

    . 2 of 3 tests passed. Total time: 2.550000 seconds Program terminated unsuccessfully.

    (C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\examples\fe>
```

Comment: I am curious - where is your Python installed (is it the default `C:\Python27` or in `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue on Ubuntu.

According to this [bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963979), there won't be any new releases of `cfx` any more. Instead, the node-based [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) ("jetpack mechanic") is the tool to go. A current minor issue, on Ubuntu the firefox binary has to be specified explicitly, e.g.

```
jpm -b /usr/bin/firefox test
```

Comment: The addon-sdk repository still seems very active, so I would keep an eye on it for a new release. https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk